# Detect UP and DOWN arrow keys in C

Tags: c, terminal

I'm a beginner in C programming and I'm building a command line interpreter. I'm getting the user input from the terminal using `fgets()` and I was trying to make a 'history' of commands using the arrow keys.

```
void receiveInput() {
  char *input = malloc(256);

  printf(">> ");
  fgets(input, 256, stdin);
  if ((strlen(input) > 0) &&
      (input[strlen(input) - 1] == '\n')) {
      input[strlen(input) - 1] = '\0';
  }
  processInput(input);
  free(input);
  receiveInput();
}
```

The function above builds the input and the problem is that I have to catch the keypress in the same time I'm trying to get the user input. Is there any way of doing this? I already found some solutions that I'm trying to understand but they seem too hard for me at this level.

Comment: The easy way to do this is to use the GNU Readline library (or its BSD equivalent, the Editline library).  Also note that a tail-call to `receiveInput` may exhaust the stack in C, unlike Scheme.

Comment: Take a look at [GNU readline library](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) which already provides the interfaces for history.

Comment: Keyboards are operating-system specific things, so how you read them will depend on whether you're running Windows, Mac, or Linux.

Comment: Is there any other way, like a workaround that will help me not to use a library? @LeeDanielCrocker I'm using Linux.

Comment: Why the recursion?

Comment: @WeatherVane beacause I want to wait for another command until you write "exit".

Comment: So what will `processInput(input);` do in that case? `free(input);` and recurse even further? Better for `processInput` to return status. The flow control is muddy.

Comment: Linux uses terminals, which are normally set up for character I/O. If you want to detect keyboard events, you have to put the terminal in a special mode and use ioctls and such. The "curses" (and ncurses) libraries are commonly used to make this easier and more portable.

Comment: Aside: the clumsy newline removal after `fgets` can be done with `input [ strcspn(input, "\r\n") ] = 0;`

Comment: @WeatherVane processInput is either executing a command or exits with exit(0). I know that it's muddy, it's just a quick code to challenge myself.